# Where on schedule C should a PO Box Rental fee go?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, small-business, schedule-c

I'm filling out my US Income tax forms and I am trying to decide where on [Schedule C](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040sc.pdf) to put the expense for a PO Box Rental.

My first guess was "Communication," but I'm not sure.  "Office Expense" or "Legal and Professional Services" also sound reasonable.

Where on Schedule C, Part II Expenses should I record a PO Box rental used for a small business?

Comment: Question -would a PO box go under rent? It is renting the space at the location where your business mail is collected? Its a mail box rent, no?

Answer (score 2):

Turbotax community had a [similar question.](http://turbotax.intuit.com/tax-questions/Schedule-C-for-Personal-Business/bX9QAwXR8r3isXabZeEZsI.html) They claim you just put it into "Office Expense".

I never understood why there are so many categories when they are just summed up and subtracted from your income. How can you possibly get in trouble for putting something in a wrong column if the final tax liability doesn't change.

Comment: Agreed. There's no material difference.  Classic example of this is expensing a $5 trashcan instead of treating it as a depriciable asset -- it's just not material to the taxes owed.